# Trying to add new row (div) for invoice and getting while page repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says I am trying to have a row repeat when I click a button so I can use PHP to hook in and pull the data and do something with it (create an invoice and bill it). The code section I have is:

```
<!-- Table row -->
<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <!--Product Table-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 table">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><form><input type="text" name="product-name[]" placeholder="Product Name"></form></td>
                    <td><form><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description"></form></td>
                    <td><form><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="1" placeholder="Quantity"></form></td>
                    <td><form><input type="text" name="price-unit[]" size="2" placeholder="Price Per Unit"></form></td>
                    <td><form><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" size="2" placeholder="Sub Total"></form></td>
                </tr>
                <p id='newrow'></p>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type='button' class="btn btn-success" id='add' value='Add item' />
    </div>

    <!--/Product Table-->
    <!-- /.col -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var n= $('.row').length+1;
        var temp = $('.row:first').clone();
        $('input:first',temp).attr('placeholder','Item #'+n)
        $('.row:last').after(temp);
    })
    </script>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Hopefully someone can help me as I have been hours now on it spread over a week and can not seem to figure it out. I am sure it is something small and I have just missed it. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Try using firebug and put the command in the console. See how it works and what errors it puts out for you.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly the problem(s) is that you are encountering?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use event delegation for the click event on add button.

Using event delegation you can that attach an event for the dynamically created elements by attaching the event on the parents that will fire for all descendants matching a selector

Read : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table row -->
                  
                  <div class="row">
                    <!--Product Table-->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 table">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td><form><input type="text" name="product-name[]" placeholder="Product Name"></form></td>
                            <td><form><input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description"></form></td>
                            <td><form><input type="text" name="qty[]" size="1" placeholder="Quantity"></form></td>
                            <td><form><input type="text" name="price-unit[]" size="2" placeholder="Price Per Unit"></form></td>
                            <td><form><input type="text" name="subtotal[]" size="2" placeholder="Sub Total"></form></td>
                          </tr>
                          <p id='newrow'></p>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                        </div>
 <input type='button' class = "add" class="btn btn-success" id='add' value='Add item' />
                     
                    </div>

                    <!--/Product Table-->
                    <!-- /.col -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click",".add",function(){
var n= $('.row').length+1;
var temp = $('.row:first').clone();
$('input:first',temp).attr('placeholder','Item #'+n)
$('.row:last').after(temp);
})
</script>



                
                  <!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Why does the OP need event delegation? The `<input type='button' class="btn btn-success" id='add' value='Add item' />` is not dynamically created.

Comment: Also, `$(document).on("click",function(){` will add a row when you click anywhere on the `document`, and not when the `add` button is clicked.

Comment: @sean yeah correct, aim was to just tell the OP why the click  event not working second time.  $('.row:first').clone(); will clone the buttton as well. Am i wrong  ?

Comment: you are correct, I missed that the button was inside the cloned row. But you still need to add `.add`, so that it is only done on button click -> `$(document).on("click", ".add" ,function(){`

Comment: @Sean yeah thanks, i reviews the answer after your comment and found that i missed the class which i added in html for the same. please refresh

Comment: Okay so I moved the button outside of the .row div I am trying to replicate and I still have the same issue, I will be reading that link you posted and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work on stack overflow with their run code thing but on my site it repeats the row div nested 3 times. Ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: there are 2 things done by me in the code, one is to attach event on parent element and second added a class="add" in the html for add button. have you applied both?

Comment: I tried copying your code snippet to my file and then commented out what I had been trying to use. Reason I did that is because it worked on here with the run code snippet thing.

Comment: could you create a fiddle of your full code ? i will have a look

Comment: @Deep Here is a google docs link as I can't copy the whole file into here too long right now. Also disregard that the navigation is not in its own file I had issues with that working always, had a 50% success rate of running for who knows what other reason.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hR4kt0Ti4dznRbn5UlZlnDgtCHUIZAa15FYEL6ZNsMU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SeaitManageit check this https://plnkr.co/edit/rYdSyqVUrgllLCxhP35U?p=preview. you have not replaced your code with mine but just put mine in yours. you also change the selector since there are multiple element with same row class in your code.

Comment: How did I not replace it? I commented out mine and put yours in same effect as me deleting mine but it keeps mine there for me to compare to and learn from.     I think you have have just found my issue with the multiple row classes.     Okay so I tired adding a div around the one .row div that I wan to replicate and it fails and repeats it all again. I did try the code you linked to and it worked fine other than the CSS was missing, and it repeats the whole thing still though once and it puts the new .row div below the button.

Comment: I am so lost on this I have been at it way too long and nothing is making sense anymore with it.

Comment: @SeaitManageit  ok let me explain you my code on the google drive link